# How to choose values of lists and add them to get a specific value in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following lists:

```py
list_1 = [5, 10]
list_2 = [50]
list_3 = [5, 10, 15]
```

and I need to get a specific value (60 in this case) choosing **maximum** one element of each list.

For example:

I could get 60 adding 10 (value from `list_1`) + 50 (`list_2`) *or* adding 10 (value from `list_3`) + 50 (`list_2`) *or* adding 5 (`list_1`) + 50 (`list_2`) + 5 (`list_3`)

How could I achieve this? Is there any function?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? Or is this merely a puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a naive brute force approach using the [`combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) functions from the excellent [`ittertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module.

As you can see, `itertools.combinations()` is in a `for` loop, so it is called 3 times to give us combinations of length 1, 2, and 3.

These combinations are then passed into `itertools.product(*lists)`, which takes one item only from each list (*iterable*).

```py
import itertools

list_1 = [5, 10]
list_2 = [50]
list_3 = [5, 10, 15]

specific_value = 60

for length in range(1, 3+1):
    list_combinations = itertools.combinations((list_1, list_2, list_3), length)
    for lists in list_combinations:
        print(f"Currect lists from combination of lists of length {length}: {lists}")
        for ntuple in itertools.product(*lists):
            summed = sum(ntuple)
            equation = " + ".join(map(str, ntuple))
            match = " [Match!]" if summed == specific_value else ""
            print(f"{equation} = {summed}{match}")
        print()
```

Output:

```
Currect lists from combination of lists of length 1: ([5, 10],)
5 = 5
10 = 10

Currect lists from combination of lists of length 1: ([50],)
50 = 50

Currect lists from combination of lists of length 1: ([5, 10, 15],)
5 = 5
10 = 10
15 = 15

Currect lists from combination of lists of length 2: ([5, 10], [50])
5 + 50 = 55
10 + 50 = 60 [Match!]

Currect lists from combination of lists of length 2: ([5, 10], [5, 10, 15])
5 + 5 = 10
5 + 10 = 15
5 + 15 = 20
10 + 5 = 15
10 + 10 = 20
10 + 15 = 25

Currect lists from combination of lists of length 2: ([50], [5, 10, 15])
50 + 5 = 55
50 + 10 = 60 [Match!]
50 + 15 = 65

Currect lists from combination of lists of length 3: ([5, 10], [50], [5, 10, 15])
5 + 50 + 5 = 60 [Match!]
5 + 50 + 10 = 65
5 + 50 + 15 = 70
10 + 50 + 5 = 65
10 + 50 + 10 = 70
10 + 50 + 15 = 75
```